# What's the neatest way to stop a Winforms window being moved around

Tags: .net, winforms, desktop-application

We have a WinForms application which runs on a touch-screen on a bit of industrial equipment.  For historical reasons which are not up for changing today, the displayed form has a normal Windows title bar.

We would like to stop people using the mouse (i.e. touchscreen) from moving the window by dragging the title bar.   We don't care if there's some other way to move the window using the keyboard.

What's the most elegant way to achieve this?  I can think of trying to subvert mouse messages if there's a mouse-down on the titlebar (though NC hit-testing doesn't at first glance seem completely obvious in Winforms), and I can think of responding to Move messages in some way which restores the window position.

But both of these seem clunky, and I have a feeling I am missing something elegant and obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nc messages are still the go I think. Syncfusion's windows form faq has the code you need. I'd paste a link, but I'm on an iPhone with no copy paste (grumble, grumble!)

Comment: http://www.faqdev.com/FAQ/WINDOWS/Windows-Forms/Form/656/How-do-I-prevent-a-user-from-moving-a-form-at-run-time

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to a bit of encouragement from DanF, I came up with this:

```
  protected override void  WndProc(ref Message msg)
  {
      const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xa1;

      switch (msg.Msg)
      {
         case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
            // To prevent people moving the window with the mouse 
            // unless CTRL is held
            if (!(GetKeyState((int)Keys.ControlKey) < 0))
            {
               return;
            }
            break;
      }
      base.WndProc(ref msg);
  }
```

Which seems to be just the thing.  Thanks all.

Comment: What about when someone presses Alt+Space followed by &Move from the context menu?

Comment: If you re-read the question, you'll see I did say "We don't care if there's some other way to move the window using the keyboard."

Comment: This doesn't prevent moving, it prevents mouse-clicks, which is great unless you need to allow the user to click on things like the close button at the lop right of the form

Comment: @rotard - In the context of the question (industrial touch screen), the idea is to prevent (well, make it hard for) people from getting 'behind' the application.  So we certainly don't have close/minimize buttons or system menus on the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

How about modify the main form event's LocationChanged, SizeChanged, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could force the window to remain maximized, if that's practical for your application.

Answer (score 0):

To handle @rotard's comment on your solution, you can block *just* movement with the mouse by the following: In your `WndProc` override, for `WM_NCHITTEST`, call `base.WndProc` *first*. If it returns `HTCAPTION`, return `HTNONE` instead.